# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166), Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'GoogleSignInAccount'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add data to firestore collection. Update function works good,

```
var kontrol;
DatayiAl(kontrol);

if(kontrol == null){
  print(5);
  verileriKaydet();
}
```

In this section if part works good, because I can see the printed 5.
But verileriKaydet() method is not working.

```
void verileriKaydet() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance.collection("skorlar").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(
        {
        "user" :  googleSignIn.currentUser,
        "skor" : marks
        }
    ).then((_){
    print("success!");
    });
}
```

And this is the getting data function:

```
void DatayiAl(var skor) async{

    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance.collection("skorlar").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
    print(value.data);
    skor = value;
    });

}
```

At the end I see the 5 printed but after that this error comes:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'GoogleSignInAccount'
```

Comment: Before using "googleSignIn.currentUser", you need to initialize "final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();". Make sure you have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the problem

```
"user" :  googleSignIn.currentUser,
```

you already have the *currentUser*  in the previous line `var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();`

I suggest you try reusing it.
You can also try creating a model, like `AppUser`, or just a `Map` from `firebaseUser`, so that it becomes more usable for your app.

on the other hand, if you still want to use the `googleSignIn.currentUser` , then you need to create a model or `Map` and then assign it to your object.

Comment: thank you, it worked after i changed googleSignIn.currentUser with firebaseUser.displayName

Comment: sounds good. plz accept the answer if it worked, and voting is a good way to thank ;)